# Location of Chrome Web Apps (PWAs)

Tags: google-chrome, web-applications, progressive-web-apps, chromium

I use PWAs on my work (Windows 10) and personal (Linux) devices.

I also sometimes "create" these Web Apps using `more tools > create shortcut > open in new window` and then from `chrome://apps` right click and create a shortcut in the application menu.

These shortcuts can then be "pinned to dock" (Win10) or "added to favorites" (Linux/Gnome).

Some of the icons have a background that should be transparent instead of black. This is easy to fix.

Where can I find these PWAs on my local devices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows 10/8/7: `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Web Applications\`

macOS: `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Web Applications`

Linux: `~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Web Applications`

Linux (Chromium): `~/.config/chromium/Default/Web Applications`

Chrome OS: `/home/chronos/Web Applications`