# Where are PWA files stored when cached for offline use?

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I have a PWA that caches the app for offline use.  Where are the files stored when you install the PWA and how do I locate them?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Location of Chrome Web Apps (PWAs)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70470471/location-of-chrome-web-apps-pwas)

Answer (score 3):

The browser stores these files for you. You can browse them via DevTools.

In Chrome you find them under DevTools => Application Tab => Cache
[image: Chrome DevTools showing Application Cache]

But I don't think you can locate them via file browser.